# JD Edwards error "Unknown JAS error has occurred. Please contact your system administrator."

Tags: service, jdedwards

I created a new enviroment, but when I'm trying to login on the web it shows me this error "Unknown JAS error has occurred. Please contact your system administrator."

I have restarted all the servers and services and verified the JDK version and everything is ok.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

See this [post](http://www.jdelist.com/ubb/showflat.php?Number=141616). As it says,

1) Open add/remove programs, make sure Ms SQL Server 2000 Driver for JDBC SP2 AND Ms SQL Server Desktop Engine (JDELOCAL) are Installed.

2) Uninstall all other Ms Sql Server instances installed (if u have any instances installed)

3) In RUN, Type services.msc , check whether MSSQL$JDELOCAL and SQLAgent$JDELOCAL have status :Started and Startup Type: Automatic. This is necessary Step

4) Restart PC.

5)Disable Anti Virus and Firewall -- they actually acts as a barrier between IPC(Inter-Process Communication).

6) start E1, wait for 30 seconds (Necessary step)

7) Then login as usual and try to logon to Enterprise one Web Page.